# Combine mysql queries into one

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a filter for the shop and need to combine several query into one. My problem is that I can't use UNION because I don't know the exact number of filter queries, so I use foreach. I have a sample code below.

```
$searchArray = array("%XS%", "%S%");

foreach ($searchArray as $value) {
    $load_sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `lm_items` WHERE LOWER(`size`) LIKE LOWER(?)");
    $load_sql->bind_param('s', $value);
}

$load_sql->execute();
$load_result = $load_sql->get_result();
```

[image: mysql image]

Comment: You question is a bit unclear. Please add some more details. Example, what can searchArray contain?

Comment: @kiner_shah I have a url request like this. ?s=XS&s=S&s=M
These are the dimensions. I take them into a file and build an array from it. Then I need to find the column has these dimensions and output it.

As you understand there can be a lot of queries in an array.

Comment: So your query is like: get all rows which has size = 'XS' or size = 'S' or size = 'M'?

Comment: @kiner_shah No. If it has XS AND S (not or);

Comment: You may need to include your table with sample data for better understanding.

Comment: How can it have both sizes at once in the same row? That doesn't make sense - unless perhaps you've denormalised your data by storing multiple values in the same field (and thus made this query trickier than it needs to be)?

Comment: @ADyson Posted an image. Yes I am storing the data in json

Comment: Any particular reason you chose to denormalise the schema like that?

Comment: If you do insist on using JSON though, then mysql has functions for searching it properly: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: @ADyson. The reason is very simple. It's easier for me to output data this way. Thanks for the link. I'll check it out.

Comment: Please look here possible solution: https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/591bd685d5a94a6a967486d0040eb7a9/php/php8/6448b2be58b6affa18be6d3b778979c5/

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments
if you do insist on using Json
This query will search for all items with "S" size

```sql
select JSON_EXTRACT(size, '$') from lm_items where JSON_CONTAINS(size, '"S"', '$')
```

You may concat all filter variables in one query

```php
// filter parameters
$searchArray = array("%XS%", "%S%");
// init query, 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `lm_items` WHERE TRUE ";

foreach ($searchArray as $value) {
    // add a new condition to query for each filter parameter
    $query .= " AND JSON_CONTAINS(size, '"?"', '$') "
}
$load_sql = $db->prepare($query);
// bind params
$load_sql->execute($searchArray);

$load_result = $load_sql->get_result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you not need UNION here. You should to run query like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_value IN ('val1', 'val2');
```

below is PHP implementation:

```
<?php   
$searchArray = ["XS", "S"]; // array values
// Place holders string '?,?' string built according values count
$place_holders = implode(",", array_fill(0, count($searchArray), "?")); 

//types string 'ss'
$sql_types  = str_repeat("s", count($searchArray)); 
$query      = "SELECT * FROM `lm_items` WHERE `size` IN (" . $place_holders . ")";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query); // prepare SQL statement
$stmt->bind_param($sql_types, ...$searchArray); // bind array at once
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$load_result = $result->fetch_all();

print_r($load_result);
```

[PHP mysql sandbox](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/591bd685d5a94a6a967486d0040eb7a9/php/php8/15cdf696ec3f4599eb728842cdcfd10f/)